# Adding a google map to a navigation drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

here is my issue. I current have a navigation drawer with 3 items. I would like one of those items to be a map. I have followed the google doc and have successful creating my map. The problem is that my markers will not show up. I know what the problem is but I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is the map fragment. As you can see I am implementing `OnMapReadyCallback` and I also have included the `onMapReady()` method. The `onMapReady()` is not being called (that's the problem) because I am not calling the `getMapAsync()` method. I do not know where I should put it let alone how to call it based on my code.

I have also included the code in my Navigation Drawer that calls the map fragment. The map xml is just like the one in the google docs example.  Like I stated before; my map does work but the markers do not show because `onMapReady()` does not get called.

Map Fragment:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(29.702182, -98.124561)).title("marker"));
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    }

}
```

Navigation Drawer Code:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // This is where the fragment view changes will be put
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Blank1Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            //fragment = new Blank2Fragment();
            fragment = new MapsFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Blank3Fragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: I made some edits to my post. Can you please tell me where the suggested code should go and how to exactly implement is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But I solved it in such a way:

```
public class Map extends Fragment {
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, mapFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(29.702182, -98.124561)).title("marker"));
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So, you need to add method `onActivityCreated` to your code (instead `onMapReady`), and a marker will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

> The `onMapReady()` is not being called (that's the problem) because I am not calling the `getMapAsync()` method.

**True.**

In your `Fragment` containing the map (**BTW it has to be a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`**) you should have a `SupportMapFragment` object that you retrieved from your XML layout.

Then, just call **`getMapAsync()`**:

```
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont call a method that initializes your map, it needs to be initialized in onCreateView method.

Write this code inside onCreateView method:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapaPrincipal);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
map = mapView.getMap();
if(map != null) {
    ... do your changes to the map
}
```

Comment: If it is usefull for you please aproove the answer. Tks in advance.